# How to set a legend item for unbound regions?

Tags: anychart

I am using AnyMap and my client wants to display some information in the legend for unbound regions.

Because I can just add a legend item for a series I am implementing an empty series and then adding a legend item on this. However as there is no country to select I do not want my legend item to be selectable. How can I prevent this?

The only solution I found for this is applying "disabled:true" to my legendItem, but then the color changes..

This is how my code looks so far

```
var unboundRegions = anyMap.choropleth();
      unboundRegions.legendItem({text: data.unbound, iconType: "square", iconFill: '#ffffff', iconStroke: '#e8e8e9', disabled: true});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent legend icon selection using "legendItemMouseDown" legend event listener - just prevent its default behavior using `e.preventDefault();`

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/blackart/de324s2t/5/)